# How to plot two dataset in point and line form in one figure in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have two dataset (each has two columns of data).  I want to use R to xyplot both dataset into one figure, while one is in point form, one is in smooth line format.

Could you mind to teach me how to do so?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options:

1) Use `plot` with the "o" (overplot) type

```
plot (x, y, t="o")
```

2) In general, as @Milktrader said, you can call plot twice with `new=TRUE`, for instance:

```
plot (x, y)
plot (x, y, "l", new=T)
```

3) Use `points`

```
plot (x, y)
points (x, y, "l")
```

4) Split the screen with `split.screen` or `layout`

```
split.screen(c(1,2))
screen(1)
plot(x, y)
screen(2)
plot(x, y, "l")
```

And there are surely many others...

Answer (score 2):

In general:

```
plot(first_dataset, type="p")
par (new=TRUE)
plot(second_dataset)
```